# Input under conditions

Tags: input

I have a main document with inputs of several others.
This is my main document

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\textbf{Years} #1}
\newcommand{\corps}[1]{#1}


\begin{document}

%\input{0022}
\input{0086}
% other input here

\end{document}
```

This is what one of my input looks like

```
\years{
\begin{itemize}
\item 2023
\item 2021
\item 2007
\end{itemize}}


\corps{lalala}
```

I would like my output to be only with the files with no "2022" in the "years" command. Namely, not inputing the files with 2022 in the "years" command.

The condition is for now in the "years" command but it can be anywhere / anyhow else.

How can I do it ?
Thank you very much, and sorry for my english !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. I'm not sure I completely understand your goal here. Could the `2022` be anywhere within the `itemize` environment that you're passing to the `\years` command? (which might be better written as an environment, but that's a separate issue). You can't really check inside the contents of a file before you `\input` it. Could you simply use some feature of the filename instead?

Comment: Maybe you could describe the larger goal of what you're trying to achieve, and we might be able to suggest a different way to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. Actually, I'm a teacher and I'm doing a bank of exercises I'm using. The years command includes the years I gave the exercise to the student. 
I want to have a document with all the exercises (that's what I have now) and I want a document with all the exercises except the ones I gave the past year. Maybe I can add it in the filename but this mean eachtime I use the document, I modify the name and then I change all the files I'm inputing it with the previous name...

Comment: Ok that helps clarify a lot. Filenames are then probably not the best solution. But I would consider keeping the year metadata in a separate file like a CSV file and using the data that way. But others may have solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alan Munn mentions in the comments, there is likely a better way to organize this data. But here's a simple way to do as you ask. The `\years` command now takes a comma-separated list of years, and it's assumed that it appears at the top of the `\input` file and only appears once in that file.

```
\begin{filecontents}{testA.tex}
\years{2023,2021,2007}

\corps{lalala}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testB.tex}
\years{2022,1986,1524}

\corps{some text}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{testC.tex}
\years{1066,1975}

\corps{some more text}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\corps}[1]{#1}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_laura_years_clist

\NewDocumentCommand { \years } { m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_laura_years_clist { #1 }
    \clist_if_in:NnTF \l_laura_years_clist { 2022 }
      { \endinput }
      {
        \subsubsection*{Years}
        \begin{itemize}
        \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_laura_years_clist
          { \item ##1 }
        \end{itemize}
      }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\input{testA}

\input{testB}

\input{testC}

\end{document}
```

[image: clist]

Comment: That's wonderful !!! Thank you so much !!! A lot of time spared thanks to you.

Comment: @LauraG If it answers your question you can “accept” it by clicking the check mark